# What would cause one Arduino to be recognized but not another?

Tags: arduino-uno, serial

I have two Arduinos, A cheap china-knockoff and an original one. I have had no problem with either of them before. But when I moved from connecting the original with a USB A-hub to running it over USB-C my computer can't find it any more.

I run OSX and tried to install a new USB serial driver. Didn't work either. Then I tried the cheap clone, same computer, same wire, same computer and it works fine.

The faulty Arduino powers up and I can reset it. So it seems to be working. What might cause this?

Comment: Do the two boards use different USB chips? I.e., the clone use CH340G?

Comment: How can I tell?

Comment: By looking. Black thing. Near the USB connector on the board.

Comment: Yeah, the clone is CH340G... what's the original one?

Comment: ATMega16U2. There's the probable difference that means one is detected and the other not. As to *why* the genuine one isn't detected, I have no idea.  The clone uses the custom CH340G driver. The original uses the default CDC/ACM driver. I have an itch at the back of my head about something to do with CDC/ACM in later versions of OS X, but I don't know what.

Comment: This might help: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8297132

Comment: Are you 100% sure the USB cable is a **data** cable, not just a power cable? A power cable will only provide power to the USB device, but no data communications.

Comment: Thx, the problems started when I went from a usb hub to usb3. @tom, yeah, it works with the chineese knockoff...